# Get Future value without Futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I want to get the value of a future function (without futurebuilder), in which I load a json file, I put this value in a text widget but it returns me this message **"Instance of 'Future void'"** I don't know why .

**helperLoadJson.dart**

```
//Load Json
Future<String> _loadAStudentAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Copie.json');
}
//Load Response
Future loadStudent([int index]) async {
  String jsonString = await _loadAStudentAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  QuotList quotList = QuotList.fromJson(jsonResponse);

 return quotList.quots[0].country;

}
```

**main.dart**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
//Get Future from helperLoadJson.dart
 Future<void> getLoadStudent() async {
    final String myQuot = await loadStudent();
    print(myQuot); // OK , return me good value
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('getLoadStudent : ${getLoadStudent()}'); // return " Instance of 'Future<void>' "
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           Text(
             '${getLoadStudent()}', // return " Instance of 'Future<void>' "
            ),
            Container(
                // child: projectWidget(),
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do that either by using `Future.then` method or `await ...` in some `async` method and calling `setState` after that but why to  do that by yourself if you have handy `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: I do that :  `@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLoadStudent();
  }

  String myQuot;
  Future<void> getLoadStudent() async {
    myQuot = await loadStudent();
    setState(() {
      myQuot;
    });
    print(myQuot); // OK , return me good value
  } `   ` . i think it's ok

Comment: yes indeed, but instead of that why not to use `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: For more flexibility, moreover I find "FutureBuilder" is quite heavy.

Comment: `FutureBuilder` is nothing but one `Future.then((v) => setState(....))` - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/65cf7de5f4/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L794 - lines 794-799, thats more or less all `FutureBuilder` does under the hood

Comment: @pskink I just needed a quick way to update a value without needing to make use of FutureBuilder, and your comment was really helpful: setState is my savior, +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
getLoadStudent()
        .whenComplete(() {})
        .then((value) {})
        .onError((error, stackTrace) {});
```

**whenComplete** is called when this future completes, whether it does so with a value or with an error.

**then** is called when this future completes with value

**onError** is called when this future completes with error.(only catches errors of type E)